# How to assign multiple options to multiple list items?

Tags: java, android

Hy !
I have two items named activate and deactivate . On the other hand, i have a list view in context menu having two list items. When i am passing my items to these two list items , both of these two are assigned to each list item. 
Actually, my intention is to pass activate to first item in list and deactivate to second item in list and so on..
What is the way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

You can put activate and deactivate in a list and assign them to the listview item by accessing through its position.As listview.getItem[position]=list[position] and I think it will solve your problem

Comment: Where i would write this code? In case of switch in onContext itemselected() function or somewhere else? ... secondly in "position "what value  i would pass? ...  Actually i am learnee of android , facing difficulty to write code !!!

Comment: Sai krishna : you did not tell me what i have asked ??